# Help me to understand Single Class Inheritance in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, single-table-inheritance

```
<?php
namespace Jo\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="resource_type", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"article" = "\Jo\Model\Article\ArticleVote", "comment" = "\Jo\Model\Article\CommentVote"})
 */
class Vote
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Jo\Model\User\User")
     */
    protected $user;


    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $weight;

    public function setWeight($weight)
    {
        $this->weight = $weight;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getWeight()
    {
        return $this->weight;
    }
}
```

And

```
<?php
namespace Jo\Model\Article;
use Jo\Model;
/**
 * @Entity
 */

class CommentVote extends Model\Vote
{
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Comment")
     */
    protected $comment;

    public function setComment(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getComment()
    {
        return $this->comment;
    }
}
```

It generates the following table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE Vote (
   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
   user_id INT DEFAULT NULL, 
   article_id INT DEFAULT NULL, 
   comment_id INT DEFAULT NULL, 
   weight INT NOT NULL, 
   resource_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
INDEX IDX_FA222A5AA76ED395 (user_id), 
INDEX IDX_FA222A5A62922701 (article_id), 
INDEX IDX_FA222A5AF8697D13 (comment_id), 
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

which looks correct.

However, when I do :

```
$commentVote = new CommentVote();
$commentVote->setComment($comment); // $comment instance of Comment
$commentVote->setWeight(1);
$em->persist($commentVote);
$em->flush();
```

I get the following error :

```
Message: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'resource_type' cannot be null
```

Do I have to manually set up the resource_type property used as a discriminator? I don't get the point to this manually if I use Single Table Inheritance over two different class.

Do I do something wrong, I couldn't find any valuable information about this kind of implementation.

thnak you.

Answer (score 0):

CommentVote is extending Vote. Vote as a resource_type. So now you have to set it for CommentVote, and it can not be null:

```
resource_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

You have to say what you want resource_type to be. I can not guess that.

You can however set that nullable in Vote:

```
/**
 * @Column(type="string", length=255", nullable=true)
 */
private $resource_type;
```

or you can set a default value for resource_type. If so, you can choose to set the default value in the __construct of CommentVote, or you can also set the value in a @PreUpdate method.

Comment: This does not work for me. When I do this, Doctrine tells me that the "resource_type" field has been defined twice (once as the descriminator column, and once as a regular column).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but that's because I was doing this:

```
<?php

/**
 * This class, although not abstract, is not intended to be instantiated, 
 * and so is not in the discriminator map.
 */
class BaseClass
{
     public static function create()
     {
          return new self();
     }
}

/**
 * This class is in the discriminator map.
 */
class SubclassOne
extends BaseClass
{
     // ...
}

$one = SubclassOne::create();
$em->persist($one);
$em->flush();
```

The problem in my case had nothing to do with Doctrine: because `self` does not use late binding, I was unknowingly getting an instance of `BaseClass` instead of `SubclassOne`. Since `BaseClass` has no discriminator mapping, the discriminator column could not be filled in by Doctrine.

I've since gotten rid of all of the `::create()` nonsense and started using regular constructors, and I'll probably make `BaseClass` abstract, too.